# How to check CPU Utilization of system calls used in a shell script while script is executing?

Tags: shell, unix

I Have a shell script which uses couple of system calls (grep,ps etc). I need to find CPU utilization for each system call used inside a script. I am using AIX unix version 5.1.Please help.

I have already tried Topas, vmstat , iostat commands, but they display overall cpu utilization of processes.

Answer (score 0):

use below commnad

ps -aef | grep "process_name"

there would be a column 'C' in ouptut, which display cpu utilization for that process.

Thanks,
Gopal

Comment: Thanks alot for helping ... Finding out CPU utilization for a single process is possible but what if i want to find system calls used by that specific process. For Example: - i run a script abc.sh, then i use command ps -flu $USER i will get detailed description of process actively running on kernel. How do i get cpu utilization of commands used inside the script abc.sh ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's available on AIX, but on Linux the `time` command is what you would use

```
time wc /etc/hosts
  9  26 235 /etc/hosts

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.004s
```

`sys` is the amount of system call time, `user` is not system call time used by the process